# EJB-like communication of REST components

Tags: java, rest

I'm designing software with different components, that need to communicate with each other through a REST interface.

I've seen and implemented solutions, where the different components of the software (deployed on the same cluster) would communicate by declaring and injecting EJB beans. This way, it's really easy to standardize the communication by defining common interfaces and DTOs in a separate .jar dependency.

This level of comfort and standardization is what I'd like to achieve with RESTful services, between Java-based components of my software.

Imagine something like this:

Let's say, I have a `REST Client` (C) and a `REST Server` (S).
I'd like to be able to communicate between them, via a common interface, which is implemented in `S` and called by `C`. This common interface is in an `API component` (I).

It would mean that `I` would have an interface:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("list")
    ResponseEntity<List<UsersModel>> getUserList(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken token);
}
```

In `C` it could be used like:

```java
public class Sg {

    private final UserController userController;

    ...

    public void method(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken token) {
        ...
        userController.getUserList(token);
        ...
    }
}
```

Lastly, in `S`:

```java
public class UserControllerImpl implements UserController {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<UsersModel>> getUserList(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken token) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The only configuration needed is to tell the client the context root (and host address) of the server, everything else is present in the common interface in the form of annotations.

Since not all components are necessarily Java-based, it is important for the REST resource to be callable in a typical REST-like way, so those Java remote service calling mechanics are out of consideration.

I was looking into JAX-RS, which seems promising, but is missing a couple of features that would be nice. For example, there isn't a common interface telling the client which endpoint on the server can the REST resource be found, neither are the method names, etc. AFAIK, on the client, you can only call the method representing the HTTP method of the request, which is a bummer.

Am I out of my mind with this spec? I'm not really experienced with REST services yet, so I don't really know if I'm speaking of something that is out of the REST services scope. Is there an already existing solution to the problem I face?

Comment: Yes. You are trying to reinvent [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). [ReST](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/soap-vs-rest-comparing-two-apis/#:~:targetText=REST%3A%20The%20key%20differences,this%20while%20REST%20uses%20URIs.) is a different style of distributed computing that deliberately leaves the details you're looking for up to implementations.

Comment: so you say that I shouldn't bother and just use JAX-RS as it was originally intended?

Comment: I can't offer universal advice, you can certainly use a known ReST endpoint to discover unknown ReST endpoints. You might want to investigate [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS#:~:targetText=Hypermedia%20as%20the%20Engine%20of,provide%20information%20dynamically%20through%20hypermedia) and [REST callbacks](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

After more thorough research, I found that `RESTeasy` already has a solution for this.

You need to use the `ProxyBuilder` to create a proxy of your interface and that's it.